# jBPM 6 modules for jBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm

I'm attempting to install jBPM 6 on jBoss EAP 6.1. The [example applications](https://github.com/jsvitak/jbpm-6-examples/tree/master/rewards-basic) that I've been working off of don't use modules and instead seem to bundle all of the required libraries into the /lib folder.

Has anyone successfully installed jBPM 6 using modules? I've attempted to create a module containing basically the JARs referenced by the example applications, but it seems that some of the persistence classes are not in my classpath.

When using the standard `persistence.xml` that has

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
```

The system does not find either of the XML files. If I manually create them, they crash on each named query noting that the objects were not mapped.

From this I'm guessing that the persistence JARs are not on the classpath at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/202312), it seems that there should be a way to do this via the `<include>` tag, however it doesn't seem to work currently. I modified my build scripts to keep bundling the required jars in the `/lib` folder as per previous versions of jBoss and it is working correctly now.